# Parsing .torrent-file using ANTLR

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr, torrent

I'am tried parsing metainfo from .torent-file using ANTLR4.

All data in a metainfo file is bencoded. The specification for bencoding:

```
dictionary = "d" 1*(string anytype) "e" ; non-empty dictionary
list       = "l" 1*anytype "e"          ; non-empty list
integer    = "i" signumber "e"
string     = number ":" <number long sequence of any CHAR>
anytype    = dictionary / list / integer / string
signumber  = "-" number / number
number     = 1*DIGIT
CHAR       = %x00-FF                    ; any 8-bit character
DIGIT      = "0" / "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" /
            "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9"
```

I'm using the following grammar:

```
grammar Bencode;

bencode: (binteger | bstring | blist | bdictionary) EOF;

binteger: 'i' INT 'e';

bstring: INT ':' STRING;

blist: 'l' (binteger | bstring | blist | bdictionary)+ 'e';

bdictionary: 'd' (bstring (binteger | bstring | blist | bdictionary))+ 'e';

INT : DIGIT+ ;

fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;

STRING : ('a'..'z')* ;
```

But faced with the next problem. 
I have following example:

```
d3:one3:twoe
```

And parser not recognise second string as `two`, but recognise as `twoe`. As a result parser not recognise end of dictionary, which ends on `e`.

Similarly, another example `d3:onel4:testee` not recognise, because first string is `onel`, not `one`.

How i can fix my grammar, whatever it was correctly for this case?

P.S. Never mind that string a not `%x00-FF`, this grammar is draft and contains other minor inaccuracies.

Comment: This seems to be above context-free language. To parse this, it requires you to catch the number of characters in the string and use it to identify the end of the string. Not sure if antlr support parsing this case.

Comment: Hi, nhahtdh. I tried following example for definition bstring:
    bstring
       : INT {chars = Integer.parseInt($INT.text); System.out.println(chars);} ':'     ({count = getCurrentToken().getStopIndex() - getCurrentToken().getStartIndex() + 1;}  STRING  ) { if (chars != count) throw new RuntimeException();}
       ;
And this example work, where length more then length string. But this don't work correctly.